# "Why are we going on/ in this side" Vs. "Why are we going by this side"?

Tags: prepositions

Imagine a couple going on the left sidewalk but this side isn't comfortable as the second side is, and then the girl asks the guy beside her "Why are we going ___ this side"? What preposition would be correct to choose in this context?

> "Why are we going **in** this side?"

or

> "Why are we going **on** this side?"

or

> "Why are we going **by** this side"?

I created a photo with an explanation to make my question understandable.

[image]

Comment: Definitely "on".

Comment: *on* because you walk on pavement. You are not by or in anything

Comment: Why are we walking on this side of the street?  Full context.

Comment: Yes the preposition is definitely "on". But "going", in this context, is not idiomatic - though the meaning is clear.  It needs to be "Why are we walking on this side..."

Answer (score 1):

On this side.

> Side
>
> NOUN
>   1A position to the left or right of an object, place, or central
>   point.
>
> ‘a town on the other side of the river’
>   ‘on either side of the
>   entrance was a garden’
>
> 1.1 Either of the two halves of an object, surface, or place regarded as divided by an imaginary central line.
>
> ‘she lay on her side of the
>   bed’

[Side](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/side)